# Are questions about availability of movies in certain format or quality on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I would like to find out if a certain movie is available in real (non-upscaled) 4K in the original wide-screen format. Preliminary research (reviews on Amazon) shows that the only available 4K version is cropped to TV screen format, and it is unclear whether it was indeed scanned in 4K or just upscaled.

Would such a question be on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

No, [it wouldn't be](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> [...]
>
> - Locating or purchasing movie or TV content

The content that is on offer on a service is possibly ephemeral and/or location-specific (e.g. Netflix doesn't offer all series and movies everywhere).

Comment: I'm not buying that the cited rule is a match. I can locate 4K bluerays myself. The question is merely what content they actually bear.

Comment: @Greendrake You didn't specify physical media, but even in that case I'd argue that it falls outside the scope of this site since it falls under "locating content". Physical media is also often region-specific, plus can be limited in availability through time. Moreover, it doesn't fit in with the first four points @ https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . Honestly, your kind of question belongs on a forum on the likes of blu-ray.com etc. where you'll find experts on the topic.